# создайте запросы, описанные ниже

Tags: sql-server

- Таблица OrderDetails. Для заказа с ID 10442 нужно выбрать сумму заказанных продуктов (в заказе было несколько продуктов для этого айди) и максимальное количество Quantity для этого заказа. Оба значения должны быть в одном запросе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой запрос

```
SELECT MAX(OrderID = "10442") AND Quantity WHERE OrderID = "10442" FROM [OrderDetails]
```

Как сделать правильно, никак не пойму

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через конструкцию `WHERE` отделяем нужный `OrderID`. Далее, считаем количество продуктов, максимальный `quantity` через аггрегирующие функции. `OrderID` берем также через `max`, если он нужен. После условия `WHERE` все оставшиеся строки будут иметь OrderID = "10442", поэтому `max` вернет 10442.

```
SELECT max(OrderID), 
       count(ProductID), 
       max(Quantity)
FROM OrderDetails
WHERE OrderID = "10442"
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]